# Submit to Google without logging in?

Tags: search-engines, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I want to submit certain web pages to Google so they can be indexed after they have been added or updated, but currently Google seems to be requiring a web master to login to do this.

I do not want to login to Google to submit my pages.

Is there any way to submit web pages to Google for indexing without logging in?

Comment: Submitting a page to Google doesn't not speed the index process, also, if your site is crawl-able, why submit it at all? If you want to increase the indexing time then you need more authority.

Comment: @SimonHayter Google only visits my site once every 3 days and there is an indexing lag on top of that. So, if I change the main page, then the new content does not get indexed until 6 days later. If I manually submit my site, then the index gets updated in 3-4 days.

Comment: Sorry but that's not how it works. Google allocates resources, those resources are based on how how much your authority your website has. The more authority you have the more resources you are allocated, more resources means a bot that remains on the site for longer and more often it returns. If you was to publish 10,000's low quality pages and expect Google to crawl them after submitting a sitemap, think again... it'll take months and months, if all of them get indexed at all.

Comment: If you want faster index times then you need to improve your authority, not only will your pages get indexed faster but your rankings will also 'shoot-up'.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no webform or tool (outside of your CMS or some paid enterprise solution) you can visit and enter a page URL and send to Google or Bing, at least not one that does so reliably. Search engines get pinged constantly as it is, and they want to make sure that you at least care enough about your website to set up and verify Google Search Console or Bing Webmaster Tools. Bing does offer a tool you can use to request a re-crawl of your site, but it's a whole site thing, not an individual page, and is still less reliable. (https://www.bing.com/toolbox/submit-site-url)

If you're running on a CMS like WordPress, most sitemap plugins offer a setting where you can ping the major search engines every time your sitemap updates with new content. However, in my experience, it is a weaker signal than the one you send when you submit via GSC or BWT. (I've run experiments where the latter yielded results within a couple of days, white automated sitemap pinging took much longer or produced no results at all, until the whole site was re-crawled anyway.)

If you don't want to potentially wait several days to be re-crawled, the best course of action is to log in and submit your new URL via the preferred, official sources or get someone else you trust to do it for you.